# Detect if div is visible in browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple collapsible divs like so

```
+--------------+
| Div 1        |
+--------------+
| Div 2        |
+--------------+
| Div 3        |
+--------------+
```

Now when I click on one of the divs it expands

Question: How do I detect that expanded div was expanded over browser window (bottom border)?

Comment: do you mean that the div is outisde of the browser window? out of bounds? out of the viewport?

Comment: get the offset y position + height and compare it to the height of the window + scroll height

Comment: See this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, it's an untested idea off the top of my head so some modification may be needed.

```
var div1Height = $("#div1").height();
var div2Height = $("#div2").height();
var div3Height = $("#div3").height();
var windowSize = $(window).height();


//assign function for on click (you'll want to change this)
$("#div1, #div2, #div3").click(function(e){
if(div1Height > windowSize){
//assuming div1 is at the top
console.log("div 1 passing extents");
}
if((div2Height + parseInt($("#div2").position().top) > windowSize){
console.log("div 2 passing extents");
}
if((div3Height + parseInt($("#div3").position().top) > windowSize){
console.log("div 3passing extents");
}

});
```